# NuSOAP - HTTP Error: no data present after HTTP headers

Tags: php, oracle, soap, nusoap

I'm getting an error from a PHP API -

> HTTP Error: no data present after HTTP headers

The API uses NuSOAP 0.9.5 .

Before the HTTP Error,  I had the error

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

so I set the `max_execution_time` to 300s.

There's no problem if I limit the number of rows in the SQL query (`rownum < 2100`), but if I remove the limit I get the HTTP Error.

Could this be a memory problem or a limitation of NuSOAP?

Specs:

> - WAMP (Apache 2.2.21, PHP 5.3.10)
> - Oracle 12c

Note: I searched for this question and I got two results, but none of them them specified using NuSOAP. One was unanswered, the other had an answer stating that the HTTP response body contained no data which doesn't answer my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a memory issue.

I increased the value of *memory_limit* in php.ini and it works fine.